# Filtering jsonb array in postgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with a jsonb field of the following type:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "98f2a810-8f29-4707-9098-759eec83b2d5",
    "Data": {
      "value": 6
    },
    "Created": "2022-12-15T10:04:04.8100461Z"
  },
  {
    "Id": "950df931-abfd-460f-916f-14b00d3e1593",
    "Data": {
      "value": "hello world"
    },
    "Created": "2022-12-15T10:04:04.9270694Z"
  }
]
```

Now I can filter records only by decomposing the jsonb array into separate lines and join them:

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(""attributes"") as x(attribute) ON TRUE
```

and filter:
`WHERE x.attribute ->> 'Id' ILIKE '98f2a810-8f29-4707-9098-759eec83b2d5' and cast(x.attribute -> 'Data' ->> 'value' as numeric) = 6`

But if I need filter by two attributes with AND operator it doesn't work(the results exclude each other).

How I can filter jsonb array without separate and join elements?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "filter directly"? Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the expected output based on your sample data?

Comment: Works for me, once I've reconstructed your fragments into something that is runnable.  It returns the single array element which matches both of those conditions.